# Creating a consolidated table in excel using few small tables with defined name ranges

Tags: excel

I have few small tables in excel whose data varies very often. All these small tables are output from a addin with defined name ranges. Now i want to create a consolidated table using these small tables.Is there a way where i can make use of the defined names of the small tables to combine them into one consolidated table?

Comment: Yes - Though if you want help you'll need to provide more information such as example ranges, formats, destination, # of sheets, etc.

Comment: For Example in the picture below the data with the named ranges is highlighted with a border.
Now i want a consolidated table with the data from the two named ranges.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/RwWkx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use VBA instead of a pivot table try this:

```
Sub Combine()
  With Sheet1
    'Copy 1st dynamic range and paste to A14 of Sheet1
    Sheet1.Range("NamedRange1").Copy .Range("A14")

    'Copy 2nd dynamic range and paste to 1 below last used row of Sheet1 column A
    Sheet1.Range("NamedRange2").Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
  End With
End Sub
```

Assumes destination cell is A14 and nothing is below this.  You'll want to clear out the existing contents when running it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

a PifotTable can take data from multiple ranges - You have to use the `Pivot Table Wizard` to access this functionality.

To access the Wizard:
If you are in 2003 or before, you will find it under **Pivot Table** on the **Data** menu
If you are in 2007 or later, then you will have to add it to the ribbon
[image: Get wizard into ribbon]

In all versions, the shortcut kets, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>P</kbd> will bring up the wizard:

[image: wizard page 1]

You can then select your ranges, and do all types of manipulation on the data.